# How to rewrite $\sigma(x) u_t = \nabla(p(x)\nabla u)$ by using partial derivative signs $\frac{\partial}{\partial } $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$\sigma(x) u_t = \nabla(p(x)\nabla u)$ (where $x$ is two dimensional).

I can do this

\begin{align}
\sigma(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \nabla[p(x)(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{x} }+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} ) ]\\
&=\frac{\partial p(x)}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{x}}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} ) + p(x)(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \vec{x}^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} )
\end{align}

Is that correct? How to write it more explicitly since $x$ is two dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite right. First, the $\nabla$ operator is independent of $t$ typically. In $n$ dimensions, we have $\nabla = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n})$.  Thus, for a scalar function $f$, we have the gradient of $f$ given by $$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right).$$ For a vector field $\vec v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, we typically do not define $\nabla \vec v$; or if we do, it is a matrix. However, in this context, I am fairly certain you want the divergence of $\vec v$ given by $$\nabla \cdot \vec v = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + \frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_n}.$$ With these operations, we see $$\nabla \cdot (f \vec v) = \nabla f \cdot \vec v + f \nabla \cdot \vec v.$$ In your case, set $f = p$ and $\vec v = \nabla u$. Then you end up with $$\sigma(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla p \cdot \nabla u + p (\nabla \cdot \nabla u).$$ Now, we typically re-write $\nabla \cdot \nabla u$ as $\Delta u$; the Laplacian of $u$. This is given by $$\Delta u =\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2} + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_n^2}.$$ Thus the final equation (in two spatial dimensions) is $$\sigma(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} + p \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_2^2}\right).$$